# Align center flutter

Tags: flutter

why the container does not align to the center? it always align to the left although I specified that it to align to the center.

```
Row(
              
              children: <Widget>[
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 250,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                     
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),

                    child: FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      child: PostBody(),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the `Row`. It defaults to `MainAxisAlignment.start` which is left.

Add this to your `Row`:

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
```

And you can remove the `Align`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution :

```html
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      width: 250,
      color: Colors.grey,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
      child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
        child: PostBody(),
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error in align Widget because the container already have align you can use it inside a container and remove Align widget if you need it in the center of screen like

```
alignment = Alignment.center
```

if you want it in the center of row you can use

```
mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.center
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. just change your widget instead of my widget.

1. Refer Row widget [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html)
2. Refer Align class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html)
3. Refer Layouts [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)

Your Code:

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Container(
          width: 250,
          color: Colors.grey,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
          child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
            child: Text('OK'),// add your PostBody(), widget here
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

try this by applying property to `Row`

```
Row(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 250,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                     
                    padding:  EdgeInsets.all(3.0),

                    child: FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      child: Text('hello'),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
```